# How to disable a form control based on the value of another form control right at initialization on reactive angular forms?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have 2 form controls, one is select another is input field:

```
      <form  [formGroup]="timeForm">
          <div>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="fullInputWidth">
              <mat-label>Sunday</mat-label>

              <mat-select formControlName="SundayStatus">
                <mat-option value="Opened">Opened</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="Closed">Closed</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>

          <div>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="fullInputWidth">
              <mat-label>Opens at</mat-label>
              <input formControlName="SundayOpen" name="SundayOpen" matInput autocomplete="off" [format]="24" [ngxTimepicker]="SundayOpen" readonly > 
              <ngx-material-timepicker #SundayOpen [minutesGap]="15"></ngx-material-timepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
       </form>
```

Inside my component I have:

```
  this.timeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      SundayStatus: ['Closed'],
      SundayOpen: [''] 
}):
```

So I want to disable the formcontrol : 'SundayOpen' when ever the value of control 'SundayStatus' is 'Closed'.

Now the problem is that the value of 'SundayStatus' is already initialized to 'Closed'.

If I put this code on input #SundayOpen:

```
[disabled]="timeForm.get('SundayStatus').value == 'Closed'"
```

It does not disable the control the first time but works once I change the drop down value to 'Opened' ==> 'Closed'

Help!

Comment: Try `timeform.controls['SundayStatus'].value === 'Closed'` If that doesn't work, please try to provide a stackblitz that reproduces the problem

Comment: Do not use `[disabled]` in your template when you use reactive form. Avoid mixing Reactive forms and Template forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to listen to valueChanges:

```
const sundayStatusControl = this.timeForm.get('SundayStatus');
sundayStatusControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  takeUntil(this._ngOnDestroy$)
).subscribe(newStatus => {
  if (newStatus === 'Closed') {
    this.timeForm.get('SundayOpen').disable();
  } else {
    this.timeForm.get('SundayOpen').enable();
  }
});
sundayStatusControl.updateValueAndValidity();
```

If you have 7 form controls, you may group them in a loop:

```
const days = [
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thirsday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday',
  'Sunday'
]
for (const day of days) {
  const control = this.timeForm.get(`${day}Status`);
  control.valueChanges.pipe(
    takeUntil(this._ngResetForm$)
  ).subscribe(newStatus => {
    if (newStatus === 'Closed') {
      this.timeForm.get(`${day}Open`).disable();
    } else {
      this.timeForm.get(`${day}Open`).enable();
    }
  });
  control.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Comment: so I have 7 days controls (sunday to saturday) here so need to do the same for each and every one of them ? :( :(

Comment: BTW this solution also did not work as the valueChanges will only work after the dropdown status has changed... I need to do disable it right on the first time.. Since the value is initailized as 'Closed' already.

Comment: @BiswasKhayargoli You may trigger it manually: `updateValueAndValidity()`

Comment: @BiswasKhayargoli updated with a solution for the week